# can I unite states in React Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I have a state with products. User may choose any product and add/delete to/from the shopping list.
In 'productsKeys' I keep keys from prod that User choose and place them to the localStorage.
In 'productsGotFromApiByKeys' there are data kept from Api-request according keys from 'productKeys' (calories, price, info)
The reason that I don't want to keep price or other information in the state 'productsKeys' as info or price may change. The problem is in code repetition. If user wants to delete a product, it must be deleted from both state. Can I somehow unite 'productsKeys' and 'productsGotFromApiByKeys' into one?

```
const initialState = {
   productsKeys: [],
   productsGotFromApiByKeys: []
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just keep only the array with the product objects with one of the properties being the key, and whenever you add/remove products just save the keys to the local storage like so

```
localStorage.setItem('productKeys', JSON.stringify(products.map(p => p.key)))
```

You can have a `useEffect` somewhere that reacts to changes in your products state in the store, if you can provide more code perhaps I can try and give a more specific answer

Comment: thank you. Couldn't guess about that simple way.